# Excel: How do I reference a pivot table group and then assign that group a value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make a risk rating system. I am trying to categorise countries into groups and then have the groups appear in a dropdown for a user.

I am struggling to find the formula/make the pivot table able to be referenced.

Complete novice to excel so I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I took Country Risk Rating data from here as an example:

https://www.knowyourcountry.com/country-ratings-table

I then assigned conditional formatting to column C.

[image]

I then assigned a risk rating based on the value in Col D.

```
=IF(AND(C2<=100,C2>=80),"Low",IF(AND(C2<=79,C2>=70),"Low-Med",IF(AND(C2<=69,C2>=60),"Med",IF(AND(C2<=59,C2>=50),"Med-High","High"))))
```

I used the table as the source data for the pivot table (although you don't really need a pivot table for this).

I used the fields, 'Risk' & 'Country' as the rows for the Pivot.  This grouped the countries by risk rating:

[image]

If required, these can then be used as the values for a drop-down list:

[image]

Ulimately ending up with:
[image]
You can also do this using dependent combo box selections (no pivot table needed).  e.g. first drop down is Risk (High, Med, Low etc.).
The first combo box contains unique distinct values from column D (risk score). The second combo box contains unique distinct values from column B (country), based on selected value in the first combo box.

You can also do this using dependent combo box selections (no pivot table needed).  e.g. first drop down is Risk (High, Med, Low etc.)  Next drop down shows values based on the selected risk.

There is a good tutorial here:

https://www.get-digital-help.com/apply-dependent-combo-box-selections-to-a-filter-in-excel-2007/